# Ethereum Wallet "The DAO" token watch widget displays more token than what I actualy have

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, the-dao

I'm using Ethereum Wallet 0.7.3 on OSX el capitan.
When I go to [the DAO hub page](https://daohub.org/creation.html) to check my token balance, it displays

> DAO Tokens owned : 3591.5

In Ethereum Wallet, the token widget displays 3701.5 DAO tokens.
[image: DAO token widget screenshot]

But when I go to my DAO account view in Ethereum Wallet it shows me the right (3591.5) token count.

[image: Ethereum Wallet account screenshot]

I only have two accounts loaded in my Ethereum Wallet, one with which I sent ETH to the DAO and my mining account. I verified that the mining account is not associated with any DAO token on [the DAO hub page](https://daohub.org/creation.html). So all token I have and that should be displayed in that widget are associated with the first account.

I used a [blockchain explorer](https://live.ether.camp/account/8397930c818292FaCB63f4A837942CEdb337Be5c) to check again the amount sent (using 3 tx) to the DAO and it's 35,915 ETH, so 3591.5 DAO tokens is the right count.

Any one experiences this strange thing ? How to explain the difference ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The DAO address indeed now owns 100 (110?) tokens. This is most likely due to someone using the data field when sending a transaction to send the tokens to The DAO address.

Basically, there is a feature that is meant for users who want to send from an exchange. As you (hopefully) know, you cannot send directly from an exchange as the DAO Tokens will be sent back to the sending address which, in this case, would be Kraken or Poloniex's or whomever's hot wallet. You would not receive your tokens.

But, you can add some data to the data field that says "Hey contract! Don't send the tokens back to this address! Send them to this address instead!". Any address can be inputted by the user into this data field, and it seems like someone inputted the DAO's address instead of an address they control.

It may have been a mistake or it may have been someone wondering, "what would happen if I sent DAO Tokens to the DAO?! LOL!"

The answer to the latter question: everyone is now super confused as to why they have more DOA tokens than they thought had. (LOL!)

Comment: So I guess the owner of the DAO contract could transfer these tokens after the DAO funding is over and make everybody account balance display back to normal. I would let them keep these tokens for their own profit if they restore the right balance. How owns these keys?

Comment: There are no keys. It's a contract. While the contract has measures in place for sending ETH (provide an accepted proposal etc etc) I'm not sure if / how the tokens could be interacted with.

Comment: are they lost forever?

Answer (score 3):

If you click on Contracts -> "The DAO", it should show you that "The DAO" has a token balance of 110 Ð.

This token balance is associated with the "The DAO"  `0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413` account and Ethereum Wallet has added this amount to your total balance.

3,591.5 + 110 = 3,701.5 .

---

I have not been able to find a definitive source explaining the additional tokens associated with the `0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413` account, but from https://forum.daohub.org/t/help-why-i-have-more-dao-than-i-actually-bought/1560/2:

> It's all correct. Those are your accounts 7.6k tokens and the token contract address owns 100 tokens (someone used the proxy function with 1 eth to make the DAO buy itself 100 tokens - no idea why). The main contract address screen won't show your tokens, it'll show the tokens of that adress. But when you watch you'll see the sum total of all accounts you're tracking hence 7.7k

This 110 Ð was 100 Ð a few days ago. Someone must have added another 0.1 ETH by the proxy function.

---

**EDIT 16/05/2016** - Following on from team member `@tayvano`'s answer.

### Tokens Assigned To Sender's Address

When you send ethers to TheDAO the normal way, the default function within the DAO contract will call the `createTokenProxy()` function with the **senders** address.

```
// The DAO contract itself
contract DAO is DAOInterface, Token, TokenCreation {
    ...
    function () returns (bool success) {
        if (now < closingTime + creationGracePeriod && msg.sender != address(extraBalance))
            return createTokenProxy(msg.sender);
        else
            return receiveEther();
    }
    ...
```

### Tokens Assigned To Specified Address

If you instead call `createTokenProxy()` with an address other than the message sender's, the TheDAO token will be assigned to the **specified** address.

Here is the `TokenCreationInterface` interface with the comment explaining how a different address can be specified as the token owner:

```
contract TokenCreationInterface {
    ...
    /// @notice Create Token with `_tokenHolder` as the initial owner of the Token
    /// @param _tokenHolder The address of the Tokens's recipient
    /// @return Whether the token creation was successful
    function createTokenProxy(address _tokenHolder) returns (bool success);
    ...
```

And here is the implementation of `createTokenProxy(_tokenHolder)` with the statement `balances[_tokenHolder] += token;`:

```
contract TokenCreation is TokenCreationInterface, Token {
    ...
    function createTokenProxy(address _tokenHolder) returns (bool success) {
        if (now < closingTime && msg.value > 0
            && (privateCreation == 0 || privateCreation == msg.sender)) {

            uint token = (msg.value * 20) / divisor();
            extraBalance.call.value(msg.value - token)();
            balances[_tokenHolder] += token;
            totalSupply += token;
            ...
            return true;
        }
        throw;
    }
    ...
```

As noted by @Tjaden, the extra data that is sent with the transaction is a call to the function `createTokenProxy()` with the DAO's address that has probably created the extra 110 tokens.

And it is still 110 tokens. From [The DAO - Creation](https://daohub.org/creation.html):
[image]

### Example Of `createTokenProxy()` Usage

By chance I was looking at the following transaction [0xfb2d580342988f20c9bd4b756555d6139f55ab2e5df2c5f99886c6195221faee](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xfb2d580342988f20c9bd4b756555d6139f55ab2e5df2c5f99886c6195221faee) in my answer to [What is the address and balance of The DAO's extraBalance account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/what-is-the-address-and-balance-of-the-daos-extrabalance-account):
[image]

The transaction is from the Poloniex wallet and includes the extra data `0xbaac530000000000000000000000000003f59b7e25819a64fc2f7199e89457593fe3500d`.

I entered the following command in `geth` to find that the first 4 bytes of the `sha3()` of the function `createTokenProxy()` matches the first part of the extra data, which is how functions are called in transactions.

```
> web3.sha3('createTokenProxy(address)').substr(0, 10)
"0xbaac5300"
```

Poloniex is using this function call when individuals purchase The DAO tokens via the [Poloniex - Create DAO Token](https://www.poloniex.com/dao/) screen.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why someone did that and what will be the use of these tokens... The dao owning itself, strange.

Comment: To be clear, calling a function of a contract *is* just extra data sent with the transaction.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

TheDAO now owns 52174.8 DAO Tokens.

Comment: Here's a spreadsheet of all the transactions made to The DAO. Would be interesting to find out where these extra tokens come from. [EthSlurp - Downloadable Excel Blockchain Data](http://ethslurp.com/data.html)

Comment: Is there any way to get them back in the real circuit, as selling them to give the ether for some charity. Otherwise these tokens are lost anyway.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

This UI Bug has been resolved in the latest release of Mist (0.7.5). If you are still seeing this issue upgrade to the latest version.