# What is the address and balance of The DAO's extraBalance account

Tags: the-dao, balances

From [The DAO - Creation](https://daohub.org/creation.html):

- In the first 14 days, The DAO tokens are created at a rate of 1 ether = 100 tokens
- In the subsequent days before the end of the creation period, the number of ethers for each 100 tokens created increases until the final rate of creation is 1.5 ethers = 100 tokens.
- The excess ethers over the 1 ether = 100 tokens is transferred to an `extraBalance` account.

What is the address and the balance of this account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command in `geth console`:

```
> var theDAOABI = [ { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "5e+22" } ], "name": "minTokensToCreate", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "2.668900014413644230605979e+24" } ], "name": "totalSupply", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "", "value": "1464426000" } ], "name": "closingTime", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [], "name": "refund", "inputs": [], "constant": false }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "", "value": "0xda4a4626d3e16e094de3225a751aab7128e96526" } ], "name": "curator", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "balance", "value": "0" } ], "name": "balanceOf", "inputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "_owner" } ], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_numberOfProposals", "value": "0" } ], "name": "numberOfProposals", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "", "value": "0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a" } ], "name": "extraBalance", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "bool", "name": "", "value": true } ], "name": "isFueled", "inputs": [], "constant": true }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "bool", "name": "success" } ], "name": "createTokenProxy", "inputs": [ { "type": "address", "name": "_tokenHolder" } ], "constant": false }, { "type": "function", "outputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_voteID" } ], "name": "vote", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "_proposalID" }, { "type": "bool", "name": "_supportsProposal" } ], "constant": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "FuelingToDate", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "value", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "ProposalAdded", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "proposalID", "indexed": true }, { "type": "address", "name": "recipient", "indexed": false }, { "type": "uint256", "name": "amount", "indexed": false }, { "type": "bool", "name": "newCurator", "indexed": false }, { "type": "string", "name": "description", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false }, { "type": "event", "name": "ProposalTallied", "inputs": [ { "type": "uint256", "name": "proposalID", "indexed": true }, { "type": "bool", "name": "result", "indexed": false }, { "type": "uint256", "name": "quorum", "indexed": false } ], "anonymous": false } ];
undefined
> var theDAOAddress = "0xBB9bc244D798123fDe783fCc1C72d3Bb8C189413";
undefined
> var theDAO = eth.contract(theDAOABI).at(theDAOAddress);
undefined
// The account that holds the extra balances
> theDAO.extraBalance()
"0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a"
// Balance of the extra balance account at 17/05/2016 19:07:35 AEST
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance("0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a"), "ether");
21026.433088706794416575
```

The DAO's balance account is at address [0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a](http://etherscan.io/address/0x807640a13483f8ac783c557fcdf27be11ea4ac7a).

The balance of The DAO's extra balance account at 17/05/2016 19:07:35 AEST is 21026.433088706794416575 ETH.

Update 19/05/2016 - There is now a [TheDAO](http://etherscan.io/token/TheDAO) page on etherscan.io showing the balances of the main DAO account and the extra balance account.

---

Following is a transaction of 10 ethers transferred to The DAO account in block [1522378](https://etherscan.io/txs?block=1522378). The token conversion rate was then 1.05 ETH = 100 tokens. In this case, the amount of `10 x (1 - (1.00/1.05)) = 0.47619048` ethers was internally transferred to the `extraBalance` account. This is the same example from [DAOHub - ExtraBalance amount](https://forum.daohub.org/t/extrabalance-amount/2168).

Here's a transaction of 10 ethers paid into The DAO account: 
[image]

And here the excess ether of 0.47619048 over the rate 1 ETH = 100 tokens was internally transferred to the `extraBalance` account:
[image]

---

**BONUS**

Here are the instructions to find out the balance of The DAO's account and the total supply of tokens created (numbers as of 17/05/2016 01:58:03 AEST):

```
> web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(theDAOAddress), "ether")
10705493.966322505531632523
> theDAO.totalSupply()
1.0705488347353040142013475e+25
> theDAO.totalSupply()/1e16
1070548834.7353041
```