# Will The DAO tokens withdraw value be 100Dao for 1.5Eth when The DAO funding will be over?

Tags: ether, tokens, the-dao, thedao-refund

As many people I sent ether for The DAO tokens when the exchange rate was 1/100. At the end of the funding, we will be able to withdraw our ether. But the final rate on the last days of the funding will be 1.5/100. So when we will withdraw our ether what will be the rate?

As an example, if I sent 1 ether and received 100 dao on the early days, will I withdraw 1.5 ether ? Or if I sent 1.5 eth for 100 Dao on the latest days will I only receive 1 eth ? What will happen with the 0.5 remaining eth?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's related to something that doesn't exist anymore and could confuse people because withdraw from the dao doesn't work the same way the post fork withdraw contract works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end of the funding, every 100 DAO you redeem, you will get 1 ETH.  Basically it doesn't matter what you paid for them.  For people who paid more, the ETH remains in DAO's [extraBalance account.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/what-is-the-address-and-balance-of-the-daos-extrabalance-account)

Comment: So for late investors it's a sort of double punishment. You pay a higher price to acquire tokens and you retrieve less ether when you withdraw. But people still invest in The DAO after the rate changed. Do they know about this ?

Comment: No it's not "double punishment": at the end when someone pays 1.5ETH, they do get 100 DAO: same amount of DAO as everyone so they are not getting less DAO.  But they did pay 0.5ETH more than if they paid at the start, and that's like an extra donation they've given to DAO.

Comment: OK, single punishment ;)