# How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens

Tags: ether, tokens, the-dao, thedao-refund

Anyone who bought DAOs in the last two weeks of The DAO crowdfunding phase paid more than 1 ether (ETH) per 100 The DAO tokens (DAO). The ETH amount in excess of 1 ETH per 100 DAOs was stored in The DAO's [extraBalance](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/what-is-the-address-and-balance-of-the-daos-extrabalance-account) account. The balance of the extraBalance account has now been transferred into the curator's multisig wallet.

As described in [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft), The DAO token holders can currently convert their DAOs into ETH at a rate of 100 DAO = 1 ETH.

How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens?

---

### The DAO Refunds

- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)
- [THIS] [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao)
- [How do I get a refund for my The DAO tokens that was split into a child DAO?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-my-the-dao-tokens-that-was-split-into-a-child-dao)
- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-on-the-ethereum-classic-chain)
- [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo)

---

See also:

- [Which accounts contributed to The DAO's extraBalance account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/how-to-find-out-which-accounts-contributed-to-the-daos-extrabalance-account)

Comment: Try to add more than one tag in future. I added some fitting ones. :-)

Comment: Is there any danger to leave my dao tokens without converting until the developers decide an easy way to refund people who paid more than 1ETH : 100DAO
???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update Mar 29 2017

The latest instructions can be found at [The DAO Refunds](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds).

---

At the hard-fork block #1,920,000 , the ETH balance from The DAO and it's child DAOs (which includes the balance from the extraBalance account) were transferred into the [Withdrawal contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xbf4ed7b27f1d666546e30d74d50d173d20bca754#code).

Immediately after the hard-fork, at block #[1,920,090](https://etherscan.io/block/1920090), the Withdrawal contact's `trusteeWithdraw()` function was called in [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa713d75d0c03b8adcac91d254aa0ad551ba86d2cb0d936f0b8bf82fff3d75b60) to transfer 463,798.08818109 ETH into [TheDAOCurator multisig wallet](https://etherscan.io/address/0xda4a4626d3e16e094de3225a751aab7128e96526).

See the **ExtraBalance** section in [The DAO’s Edge Cases Multisig (Post Hard Fork)](https://medium.com/edge-cases-multisig-phf-official-channel/the-daos-edge-cases-multisig-post-hard-fork-2f107380bd61#.qdjyu4d9b) by Griff Green for the refund process being planned.

You should be able to find your account that contributed to the Extra Balance account in [github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData) with further details in [Which accounts contributed to The DAO's extraBalance account?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7390/which-accounts-contributed-to-the-daos-extrabalance-account):

- Tab Separated Value format: [CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt)
- Excel format: [CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.xlsx](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.xlsx). Use File -> Save As. Then open from your computer.

**Notes:**

- **Make sure that you have access to the original account and passphrase to unlock the account.**
- **Your extraBalance amounts should be correct in the https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.xlsx spreadsheet.**
- You may want to transfer your ETHs after you have withdrawn them. To prevent the replaying of your ETH transfer transaction on the non-hard-forked Ethereum Classic chain, see [How to conditionally send ethers to another account post-hard-fork to protect yourself from replay attacks](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo).

#### Update 08:07 Sep 13 2016 UTC

From [ExtraBalance Withdraw Contract to be Funded on September 15th](https://medium.com/curator-multisig-phf-official-channel/extrabalance-withdraw-contract-to-be-funded-on-september-15th-a800b4d746f0#.2mbcbpa59) by `Griff Green`, the Withdrawal contract will be funded by the curators on Sep 15 2016. You will then be able to withdraw your ethers using the methods listed below. You will find a more detailed guide to executing the Withdrawal contract using the Ethereum Wallet (similar to Method 2 below) in this linked article. Check that the ETH balance of [0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B](https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B#code) is non-zero before trying to execute your withdrawal.

#### Update 14:08 Sep 17 2016 UTC

The Withdrawal contract has been topped up by the curators with 344,917.580854976758120496 ETH. **You can now execute your withdrawals!**

Following are 3 methods to withdraw your funds:

- Method 1 - MyEtherWallet
- Method 2 - The Ethereum Wallet
- Method 3 - `geth`

---

### Method 1 - Withdrawing Using MyEtherWallet

**Update 07:00 Sep 17 2016 UTC** From `@tayvano`:

> <strike>Please make sure the funds have been depositted by checking that [the extraBalance Withdraw Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b) has a balance before attempting to withdraw. We have pushed this live as we are unavailable until the night of September 17th. Thank you.</strike>

Run MyEtherWallet from https://www.myetherwallet.com/#the-dao (Be careful as there are bogus MyEtherWallet phishing sites with similar URLs popping up over the internet aiming to steal your private keys.)
[image]

---

### Method 2 - Withdrawing Using The Ethereum Wallet

**UPDATE 05:22 Sep 8 2016 UTC - The [ExtraBalWithdrawal contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B#code) has been upgraded - replace your old version if you have already set it up. Also note that the Withdrawal contract has not been filled yet.**

**UPDATE 06:04 Sep 9 2016 UTC** - @ledgerwatch has created the document [How to withdraw from extraBalance refund contract](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1rYnz78Su23wxFu2cjvNLg1cMie5WgZoGOUp-ctKnsRY/edit) that includes some steps for replay protection.

Make sure that you have downloaded [Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.8.1) or later.

The first time you start Ethereum Wallet 0.8.1, select "Yes" to the question "Do you want to activate the chain in which funds linked to the exploit are restored to a contract where they can be withdrawn by The DAO token holders?". You have now made the choice to use the hard-forked Ethereum chain.

#### Method 2 - Step 1 - Watch `ExtraBalToken` Contract

In Ethereum Wallet, select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on WATCH CONTRACT.

- Enter a CONTRACT NAME of `ExtraBalToken`
- Enter a CONTRACT ADDRESS of `0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2`
- Enter in JSON INTERFACE field the following text: `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"seal","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"data","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"fill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"sealed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]`
- Click OK. Your Watch Contract should look like:
  [image]

#### Method 2 - Step 2 - Watch `ExtraBalWithdrawal` Contract

In Ethereum Wallet, select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on WATCH CONTRACT.

- Enter a CONTRACT NAME of `ExtraBalWithdrawal`
- Enter a CONTRACT ADDRESS of `0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b`
- Enter in JSON INTERFACE field the following text: `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"clawback","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mainDAO","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"trustee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"}]`
- Click OK. Your Watch Contract should look like:
  [image]

#### Method 2 - Step 3 - Execute `ExtraBalToken.Approve`

This will approve the transfer of the tokens from your account to the `ExtraBalWithdrawal` contract. Make sure that you send 0 ethers as this transaction may be replayed on the Ethereum Classic chain.

Select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on **EXTRABALTOKEN**.

- In the **Balance of** field on the left hand side of the page under READ FROM CONTACT, enter your account address, **ALL IN LOWERCASE**. Your withdrawal balance in wei should be displayed under your address.

  - Copy this balance figure
- On the right hand side of the page under WRITE TO CONTRACT

  - Select function **Approve**.
  - In **spender**, enter `0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b`, the address of the `ExtraBalWithdrawal` contact.
  - Copy the value in the **Balance of** result from the left hand side of the page and paste this figure into the **value** field.
  - In **Execute from**, select your account.
  - Enter **0** as the number of ETH under the Send ETHER field.
  - Click on the EXECUTE button, enter your password and confirm.

Here is a screen image:
[image]

#### Method 2 - Step 4 - Execute `ExtraBalWithdrawal.Withdraw`

**<strike>--- DON'T EXECUTE THIS INSTRUCTION JUST YET. The curators have not filled the `extraBalWithdrawal` contract and the execution will fail. This post will be updated when you are able to execute this script ---</strike>**

This will withdraw ETH from the `ExtraBalWithdrawal` contract to your account. Make sure that you send 0 ethers as this transaction may be replayed on the Ethereum Classic chain.

Select the CONTRACTS page in the top menu. Click on **EXTRABALWITHDRAWAL**. On the right hand side of the page under WRITE TO CONTRACT, Select function **Withdraw**. In **Execute from**, select your account. Enter **0** as the number of ETH under the Send ETHER field. Click on the EXECUTE button, enter your password and confirm. Here is a screen image:

[image]

---

### Method 3 - Withdrawing Using `geth`

**UPDATE 05:22 Sep 8 2016 UTC - The [ExtraBalWithdrawal contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B#code) has been upgraded and the code below has been tested. Note the new address and ABI in the `geth` script below.**

Make sure that you are running [geth version 1.4.10](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum) or later. And run your geth commands with the `--support-dao-fork option` so that you are on the hard-forked blockchain.

**<strike>--- DON'T EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING COMMANDS JUST YET. The curators have not filled the `extraBalWithdrawal` contract and the execution will fail. This post will be updated when you are able to execute this script ---</strike>**

```
user@Kumquat:~$ geth --support-dao-fork console
// Allow chain to sync
var account = "{your account}".toLowerCase();
personal.unlockAccount(account, "{your account password}")

var extraBalTokenAddress = "0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2";
var extraBalTokenABIFragment = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"}, {"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"}];
var extraBalTokenContract = eth.contract(extraBalTokenABIFragment).at(extraBalTokenAddress);    

var extraBalWithdrawalAddress = "0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b";
var extraBalWithdrawalABIFragment = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"type":"function"}];
var extraBalWithdrawalContract = eth.contract(extraBalWithdrawalABIFragment).at(extraBalWithdrawalAddress); 

var balance = extraBalTokenContract.balanceOf(account);
console.log("Your extraBalTokenContract.balance() for " + account + " is " + web3.fromWei(balance, "ether") + " ethers");

// Approve the transfer of your tokens from the extraBalToken contract
// to the extraBalWithdrawal contract
var approve = extraBalTokenContract.approve(extraBalWithdrawalAddress, balance, {from: account, value: 0});
console.log("approve() returned " + approve);

// Wait for approve() to be mined. Repeat checking using the following command until you get a non-null result.
eth.getTransactionReceipt(approve).blockNumber;

var withdraw = extraBalWithdrawalContract.withdraw({from: account, value: 0});
console.log("withdraw() returned " + withdraw);

// Wait for withdraw() to be mined. Repeat checking using the following command until you get a non-null result.
eth.getTransactionReceipt(withdraw).blockNumber;

// Your withdrawal should now be complete. Check your account balance has received the withdrawal amount.
web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(account), "ether");
```

---

### ExtraBalToken Contract

@ledgerwatch in [thedao.slack.com/messages/extrabal_community](https://thedao.slack.com/messages/extrabal_community/) deployed the ExtraBalToken contract to [0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2#code).

```
contract ExtraBalToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to it */
    function () {
        throw;     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
    }

    uint constant D160 = 0x10000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

    address public owner;

    function ExtraBalToken() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    bool public sealed;
    // The 160 LSB is the address of the balance
    // The 96 MSB is the balance of that address.
    function fill(uint[] data) {
        if ((msg.sender != owner)||(sealed))
            throw;

        for (uint i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
            address a = address( data[i] & (D160-1) );
            uint amount = data[i] / D160;
            if (balanceOf[a] == 0) {   // In case it's filled two times, it only increments once
                balanceOf[a] = amount;
                totalSupply += amount;
            }
        }
    }

    function seal() {
        if ((msg.sender != owner)||(sealed))
            throw;    
        sealed= true;
    }    
}
```

The contract ABI is: `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"seal","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"data","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"fill","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"sealed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]`.

@ledgerwatch then `fill(...)`ed the ExtraBalToken contract with the extraBalance values generated from a script similar to my [getTheDAOCreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/getTheDAOCreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4) script. The results from my script can be found at [CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.txt) or [CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.xlsx](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/blob/master/CreatedTokenEventsWithNonZeroExtraBalance_v4.xlsx).

I have tested the ExtraBalToken contract - see the reconciliation script and report at [github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/ExtraBalTokenValuesReconciliation](https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOData/tree/master/ExtraBalTokenValuesReconciliation).

The contract was then `seal()`ed in block [#2,202,674](https://etherscan.io/block/2202674).

---

### `ExtraBalWithdrawal` Contract

**UPDATE 05:22 Sep 8 2016 UTC**
The `ExtraBalWithdrawal` (`WithdrawDAO` in the source code) has been upgraded and deployed to a new address. `trusteeWithdraw(...)` has been replaced with `clawback()`.

@ledgerwatch deployed the upgraded contract to [0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b](http://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6ae4f479f7164792b318b2a06c759833b#code).

```
// Refund contract for extraBalance
// Amounts to be paid are tokenized in another contract and allow using the same refund contract as for theDAO
// Though it may be misleading, the names 'DAO', 'mainDAO' are kept here for the ease of code review

contract DAO {
    function balanceOf(address addr) returns (uint);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint balance) returns (bool);
    uint public totalSupply;
}

contract WithdrawDAO {
    DAO constant public mainDAO = DAO(0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2);
    address constant public trustee = 0xda4a4626d3e16e094de3225a751aab7128e96526;

    function withdraw(){
        uint balance = mainDAO.balanceOf(msg.sender);

        if (!mainDAO.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, balance) || !msg.sender.send(balance))
            throw;
    }

    /**
    * Return funds back to the curator.
    */
    function clawback() external {
        if (msg.sender != trustee) throw;
        if (!trustee.send(this.balance)) throw;
    }
}
```

The contract ABI is: `[{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"clawback","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"withdraw","outputs":[],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mainDAO","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"trustee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"type":"function"}]`.

**NOTE** This contract is yet to have the ethers added for The DAO token holders to withdraw.

---

### Further References

- [Hard Fork Specification](https://blog.slock.it/hard-fork-specification-24b889e70703#.s6ch8t3td)
- [Options in the Hard Fork](https://blog.slock.it/options-in-the-hard-fork-90e467483c0#.immnjexuh)

Comment: I am posting the following as an example to check if I am using the correct approach of verifying how many ether I may receive. Checking my transactions on Etherscan, I think I paid 100 ether into The DAO during the final phase (at 1.5 eth per 100 DAO). That was spread over a total of 7 transactions paid from the same single ether address. Searching Arachnid's [refund calculations](https://github.com/Arachnid/extrabalance/blob/master/extrabalance.json) I can see my address listed as follows. [ "my address", "33000000000000001049"
], I'm not sure what the long number means? I'm guessing it mean

Comment: Confirmed that you have 33 ETH in the ExtraBalance account in the _v3.xls spreadsheet.

Comment: And it is certainly, of all I can not understand, when I get my ETH from the extra balance? that's my wallet 0x5ed61b8839E823884B68Cefb915BfC0846272b6c

Comment: Can you check mine? I should get about 5 to 6 ETH refunded since I brought DAO at the last moment. My ETH address: 0x70aD044822570A44F2addf89f0B1c16A70FF44dB. I saw my address in the spreadsheet as well.

Comment: @Volodka, your extraBalance contribution is 36.666666667 ETH. @ Unknown, your extraBalance contribution is 5.5 ETH. Any others, just check your balance and if it is correct then all you have to do wait until the trustees are ready are refund the amounts. They are currently tied up refunding the (more complicated) split DAOs. If your amounts are not correctly listed in the spreadsheet under the TokenOwner column then please tell me.

Comment: I noticed in the spreadsheet, some of the wallets indicate "Proxy" while others indicate "Owner". In my case, the wallet says "Proxy", even though I own the ETH wallet in question (can access it right now on myetherwallet.com). Will they not sound out extra balance to "Proxy" wallet holders?

Comment: My withdraw transaction gets stuck somehow, while my approve succeeds..
[EtherScan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3c37cc4517327bfebab0bf7119ef21380dbc6a63d525dcec9f30f0bf3999c1af)

Comment: @PaulduLong , the curators have not topped up the extraBalWithdraw contract yet. I'll announce it as an update in this Q&A when the curators decide to do this (or any alternate method). Just check back periodically.

Comment: All of these really great instructions, assume that your DAO Tokens, were bought from your MAIN ACCOUNT CONTRACT, and not from your WALLET contract....   

How can one use the following instructions (especially the simpler ones closer to the top) if one bought the dao tokens from your wallet -
  
https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds    

All of the instructions require you to enter a base account address, which if you do, show you own ZERO doa tokens, you can check the balance of your wallet, but can't refund Extra Balance, normal eth, and etc

Answer (score 2):

People who think are entitled to the extraBalance
can check their balance also on these two file results

- [simple address-balance](https://github.com/lyricalpolymath/Ethereum_DaoExtraBalanceOwners/blob/master/02_outputs/output_02_NickFormat.json)
- [addresses, balance and all transactions](https://github.com/lyricalpolymath/Ethereum_DaoExtraBalanceOwners/blob/master/02_outputs/output_01_full.txt)

As of Friday 26th of August the other 2 files by Arachnid and Bokkypoobah have small rounding problems in their ETH calculation. (Bokkypoobah is off only by 0.000000000086360144 ETH so you can trust his results too)

Comment: Hi @b25, thanks for providing another check. I later worked out how to solve the rounding problems summing The DAO token numbers using BigNumber and `.plus(...)` - https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOETCTokenBalance/blob/master/getTheDAOTokenBalance#L92-L118 but have left my answer as-is as the figures are good enough. Thanks again.