# Fail to withdraw ExtraBalance

Tags: go-ethereum, dao

I was hoping somebody could help me to withdraw ETH from the DAO Extrabalance withdraw contract. I followed the instructions in this thread: 
[How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao)

When I submit the Approve transaction it runs, but the Withdraw function fails: "invalid jump destination (PUSH1) 2". I checked and I should be entitled to 49 Eth.

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3c37cc4517327bfebab0bf7119ef21380dbc6a63d525dcec9f30f0bf3999c1af

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As noted in the linked post, the Withdrawal contract has not been filled yet. I'll update the linked post when (/if) the Withdrawal contract has been filled and ready to be used.