# I am in the Extra Balance overview - how I get my Dao/ETH. I am using MyEtherWallet

Tags: myetherwallet, thedao-refund

Sorry - I guess the answer is somewhere here in the forum, but cannot dig through all forum entries. Perhaps someone knows the answer.

I paid 1.5 ETH for one DAO Token and used MyEtherWallet.
I found my Adress in the Extra Ballance overview and all is fine.
Now, how I can get my extra Balance. Is it possible with my Wallet?

Regards
Tobi

Comment: Details are in http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao . Note that the curators are yet to transfer the ethers into the Withdrawal contract so the withdrawal cannot be done yet. I'll update the linked post when (/if) the withdrawal contract is ready to be executed to get your refund. You may have to download the Ethereum Wallet and the hard-forked blockchain to execute this refund.