# How to get the token-balance of an external token in my contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, balances

I'm building a token contract with a sell and buy function. User should be able to buy my token not only for eth but also for another token, that I define. Therefore I need the balance mapping of the external token in my contract. I've tried:

```
contract externalToken {
   function transfer(address receiver, uint amount){  }
   mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf; }
```

and in my buy function:

```
... 

amount = externalToken.balanceOf[msg.sender] / buyPrice; 

...
```

But it shows this error:

> Indexed expression has to be a type, mapping or array (is function (address) returns (uint256))
>               if (exchangeToken.balanceOf[msg.sender] < buyPrice) throw;

How to do that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao) for a working example.

There is an `ExtraBalToken` contract with a `balanceOf(...)` method:

```
contract ExtraBalToken {
    ...
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    ...
}
```

To access the `ExtraBalToken.balanceOf(...)` from `WithdrawDAO`:

```
contract DAO {
    function balanceOf(address addr) returns (uint);
    ...
}

contract WithdrawDAO {
    DAO constant public mainDAO = DAO(0x5c40ef6f527f4fba68368774e6130ce6515123f2);
    ...

    function withdraw(){
        uint balance = mainDAO.balanceOf(msg.sender);

        if (!mainDAO.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, balance) || !msg.sender.send(balance))
            throw;
    }
    ...
}
```